# Is there Ubuntu's analogue of snapshot.debian.org?

Tags: package-management

Debian users have a kind of "wayback machine": [snapshot.debian.org](http://snapshot.debian.org/) , which is really great.

There **are** regressions sometimes, and if I don't have local deb package with old version, I'm getting sad sometimes. Having a wayback machine like this is very helpful.

I can't find analogue of it for Ubuntu. Have I missed it?

Comment: There does appear to be a [`http://snapshot.ubuntu.com/`](http://snapshot.ubuntu.com/) link - though it looks like it was for Ubuntu 7.10/8.04 only...

Comment: Maybe http://distrowatch.com/index.php?distribution=ubuntu works for you.

Comment: snapshot.ubuntu.com seems to be a completely different quality than snapshot.debian.org. snapshot.ubuntu.com only contains a handful manually-made snapshots from 2008 while snapshot.debian.org virtually contains snapshots for every second since 2005-03-12

Answer (score 7):

To use the snapshot service, users must append the desired snapshot date to the repository URL as a parameter when making a query. For instance, adding lines like:

`deb https://snapshot.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/20230401T000000Z lunar main` in **/etc/apt/sources.list** will retrieve a snapshot of the Ubuntu archive for the indicated timestamp.

Comment: As of 2024-03-18 I'm not sure that snapshot.ubuntu.com is being updated properly; I don't see recent snapshots there.

Answer (score 6):

**Update: there is a new service that provides exactly this! See @Rajan Patel's answer.**

Unfortunately there is no current exact equivalent. However, Launchpad does keep all the historical data required, and you can access this directly.

For example, for the package `hello`:

- Go to the Launchpad package page: https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hello
- From here, you can [View full publishing history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/hello/+publishinghistory).
- From this page you can work out exactly what version was published for a given release at a particular time you're interested in.
- Click on the version string. This gives you the information Launchpad holds relating to that particular version.
- You can download the sources for this particular version from this page.
- From here, click on your architecture in the Builds section on the right. The release stated here relates to the release the build was performed on, not necessarily the release the version was published in, so won't worry about the release stated.
- You can get download the debs from the "Built files" section at the bottom, and even see the build log.

Comment: I've been using this way to track the "unpublished" releases for a long time, the only pity is it consistently removes old binary packages.

Comment: snapshot.ubuntu.com now exists as a new service! See (and please upvote) the other answer!

Answer (score 0):

StableBuild (disclaimer: I'm involved in the company) has daily snapshots of the full Ubuntu (versions 18.04 and up) package repositories (and some popular PPAs) starting 6 September 2023. [Docs](https://docs.stablebuild.com/mirrors-and-caches/os-package-registry-ubuntu-debian-alpine) and [snapshot list](https://debmirror.stablebuild.com/) - works exactly the same as the Debian snapshots - but note that this is a paid service.

Alternatively, [here's a tutorial](https://www.stablebuild.com/blog/create-a-historic-ubuntu-package-mirror) on setting up your own snapshot server using zfs and apt-mirror - that's what we used to run at my company before.